# Can wkhtml2pdf support CSS counters?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have counter-reset and counter-increment working fine in HTML, but they are not appearing in the rendered PDF.  Are they supported? (An hour of Googling didn't help.)

Here is my CSS. Again, this works fine in HTML, but does not appear in the PDF.

```
body {
 counter-reset: h3counter 1;
 counter-reset: h4counter 1;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3counter;
}

h3 {
  counter-increment: h3counter;
  counter-reset: h4counter;
}

h3:before {
  content: counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}

h4 {
  counter-increment: h4counter;
}

h4:before {
  content: counter(h3counter) "." counter(h4counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}
```

Comment: Is not working to me neither, have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works (in wkhtmltox.dll version 0.11.0.0), but only in simple cases. I just ran into the problem that the counter seems to reset when the heading tags (h1, h2, h3) are not direct siblings - i.e., each is wrapped in a div. When the headings are adjacent, as in:

```
<h2>..</h2>
<h3>...</h3>
<h3>...</h3>
```

wkhtmltopdf numbers correctly; in this case:

```
<h2>...</h2>
<div>
  <h3>...</h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>...</h3>
</div>
```

it does NOT. The two h3's get the same number.